# Error management in Spring Cloud Stream with Kafka Stream

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

For a project, I use Spring Cloud Stream with Kafka as binder with several Spring Boot Apps using a Kafka stream (KStream). The goal is to have a pipeline of Spring boot apps in Spring Cloud Data Flow.
I would like to know how best to manage exceptions raised during the stream because an uncaught exception stops the Kafka stream and the Spring boot App. I would prefer to redirect the message causing the exception into a dead letter queue.

If I replace Spring Cloud Stream by Spring Integration, I have the concept of error channel available but Kafka handles the scaling very well so I am not sure this is a good solution.

In the [Spring Cloud Stream doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Fishtown.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/_apache_kafka_streams_binder.html#_handling_non_deserialization_exceptions) there is an example with a DLQ bean and a try/catch exception that sends the message to it using the low-level Processor API of the Kafka Stream.
I have tried a similar approach with a branch in my Kafka Stream with a second output to the DLQ. The separation is made on the type of the object and I return a different object in the catch section.

What's the best solution to handle exception without stopping the Kafka stream ? Is the branching solution any good ? Any information regarding a new Kafka/Spring Cloud Stream error management in the near future?

Thanks !

Comment: I'm working through error handling right now, so while I don't have an answer for you I do have a link to the documentation for the solution I have been working with to some success. The @ServiceActivator method catches exceptions and you can write your custom handling logic there. https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_application_error_handling

Comment: I think that the `@ServiceActivator` works with Spring Integration and not with Kafka Stream

Comment: `@ServiceActivator` does use Spring Integration to function, but you can handle the errors using it and republish to another topic or perform other handling from your Kafka Stream errors.
Alternatively, you could use the Dead Letter Queue support to publish your message with errors to DLQ topic and then consume them using a `@StreamListener` on the DLQ topic.